# Ubuntu Node.js Express Server Error "Cannot GET //test"

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu-server

I've tested the following node.js express server on my local maschine (Windows 10) and it worked as expected.

```
// Imports
const express = require('express');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');

// app
const app = express();

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// Get static path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Get requests
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.end('Hello World');
});

// Validation test
app.post('/testSubmit', [
    check('mail').isEmail(),
    check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
], (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    console.log(req.body);

    res.end();
});

// Start listening
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server started on Port 3000');
});
```

**Error:**

But now I uploaded my code to the ubuntu server and there I get the error "Cannot GET //test" when I try ro call myserv/api/test.

The same accures with myserv/api/testSubmit ("Cannot POST //testSubmit").

**What works:**

Static content works on ubuntu, if I call myserv/api/ I get the content of index.html which is located in the "public" folder.

**What i have tested so far:**

- Removing the static content code > no effect
- Updated Node.js and NPM > no effect
- npm install > no effect
- chmod -R 777 on my node folder > no effect

Does anybody know what I'm missing?

Comment: I believe when you want to send a data, you should say res.send("Hello World") instead of res.end()

Comment: What is the URL that you are providing?? It should be ``/test`` and not ``//test``.

Comment: In the Browser i call "mydomain/api/test" (where api is routed to the node server on port 3000) and as you can see in the code above i listen for "/test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, it has nothing to do with node.
The problem was the Reverse Proxy which i use to run node.js together with apache.

Windows:

```
ProxyPass http://192.168.3.132:3000
ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.3.132:3000
```

Ubuntu:

```
ProxyPass http://192.168.1.12:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /api http://192.168.1.12:3000/
```

I just had a / after the URL (only on my Ubuntu server) that doesn't belong  there